# SSLHandshake error in JDK 11.0.6_10 but works fine in Java8

Tags: java, ssl

Compared the cacerts file and updated the JDK11 with missing certs no help.
Even tried to load the cacert file from java8 using -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore option.

Here is the error and I'm using the -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake argument. Anything specific to keep in mind when moving from Java8 to JDK11?

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1B|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9|2020-09-10 12:57:42.782 PDT|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|1B|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9|2020-09-10 12:57:42.797 PDT|TransportContext.java:312|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:291)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:180)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.okta.commons.http.httpclient.HttpClientRequestExecutor.executeRequest(HttpClientRequestExecutor.java:186)        at com.okta.commons.http.RetryRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(RetryRequestExecutor.java:147)
        at com.okta.commons.http.RetryRequestExecutor.executeRequest(RetryRequestExecutor.java:120)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.execute(DefaultDataStore.java:443)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.lambda$getResourceData$1(DefaultDataStore.java:196)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:47)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.cache.WriteCacheFilter.filter(WriteCacheFilter.java:34)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:52)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.cache.ReadCacheFilter.filter(ReadCacheFilter.java:42)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultFilterChain.filter(DefaultFilterChain.java:52)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResourceData(DefaultDataStore.java:208)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.ds.DefaultDataStore.getResource(DefaultDataStore.java:177)
        at com.okta.sdk.impl.client.DefaultClient.listUsers(DefaultClient.java:2244)
        at org.sutterhealth.accountlinker.service.okta.OktaService.getUserByGuid(OktaService.java:104)
        at org.sutterhealth.accountlinker.web.controller.ValidateController.validateAndRedirect(ValidateController.java:59)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)}

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1B|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9|2020-09-10 12:57:42.797 PDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1360|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1B|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9|2020-09-10 12:57:42.797 PDT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1379|close the SSL connection (initiative)
```

Captured wireshark for both java8 and 11 - Noticed below difference in java11 client connect. Using tslv1.2 though, any significant issue here?

```
 Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
                Type: psk_key_exchange_modes (45)
                Length: 2
                PSK Key Exchange Modes Length: 1
                PSK Key Exchange Mode: PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment (psk_dhe_ke) (1)
            Extension: key_share (len=71)
                Type: key_share (51)
                Length: 71
                Key Share extension
```

Java 11 Error - It does populate the server name (host-name)???

```
javax.net.ssl|INFO|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.814 PDT|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.814 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.814 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: cookie
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.814 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.814 PDT|PreSharedKeyExtension.java:633|No session to resume.
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.814 PDT|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.829 PDT|ClientHello.java:653|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "4A 90 84 06 22 50 AA 16 13 00 5E E2 66 42 55 CF 18 C2 AB A9 39 97 17 C3 C3 C1 7F 47 7B 41 91 D3",
  "session id"          : "AF 3A 8B 45 00 7B 4E 37 77 DD 7C F5 50 D7 90 8B 50 6B 0D 18 0B FB 3B 25 D4 5A 93 57 40 0A 87 15",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=xxxxxx.okta.com
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [
        {
          "named group": secp256r1
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 04 3B B3 A1 E8 30 E8 AA   5D 8D E1 C1 DB 07 75 1C  .;...0..].....u.
            0010: D4 F6 48 29 31 B8 FC BD   A9 B1 56 86 57 99 76 7C  ..H)1.....V.W.v.
            0020: A6 D0 62 56 AC BA D3 1A   29 09 2B 46 F6 0B CC A7  ..bV....).+F....
            0030: E6 BE FB C3 C7 84 E2 6F   77 97 9F 27 FB 39 1C 8D  .......ow..'.9..
            0040: 5C
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.845 PDT|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|16|https-jsse-nio-443-exec-4|2020-09-14 09:27:29.861 PDT|TransportContext.java:312|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:291)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:180)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1151)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
```

Comment: There are no error messages here, only warnings and debug messages. These don't point out any error, i.e. you are missing probably the relevant part in your question.

Comment: If you are able to identify a few lines of code that might be the source of the issue, and if you inclue them in this question then it will be easier for someone to answer why there is this discrepancy.

Comment: What value(s) are you using on `javax.net.debug`? If you use e.g. just `ssl` j8 below 8u261 includes trustmanager by default, but j11 does not; you must specify it explicitly. Failing to log it doesn't mean it didn't happen, and you show no evidence or reasoning that you have a problem involving certs/truststore at all.

Comment: Updated the post with error message... When running using jdk11 I do not see this sort line 'trustStore is: D:\java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\security\cacerts'. So I tried specifying the the truststore using the option trustStore is: D:\java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\security\cacerts... Thats when I see only like 5/6 certs being imported into the runtime rather than all that are listed in the cacerts file.

Comment: Used the argument -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore to specify truststore.

Comment: New Java tries to use TLS1.3, and it is known to cause problems. Try your app with TLS 1.2: `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2`

Comment: do you know what versions of tls the server you are trying to connect to supports?

Comment: yes TLSv1.2. Client hello is using 1.2 and the successful response in Java8 from the Server hello is 1.2 as well.

Comment: yeah, then i'd recommend trying what @PakUula suggested (disabling tls 1.3 in java 11)

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but too much for comments.

First, **j11 *IS* loading the certificates**. The *logging* changed and j11 up (also 8u261 up) no longer *logs* trustmanager activity by default if e.g. you use `javax.net.debug=ssl`. As I commented, you need to use e.g. `javax.net.debug=ssl:trustmanager` or in this case `javax.net.debug=ssl:trustmanager:handshake` since you also want to see that.

**But this is not a certificate/truststore problem**. First, "*Received* ... handshake_failure" CANNOT EVER be caused by a negative result or even bug in local validation. Anyone who tells you to work on or look at the truststore for this symptom doesn't know what they are talking about and is wasting your time. Second, the trace clearly shows it is happening before/without the server even *sending* its certificate, and due to the causality of the universe, the certificate can only be checked *after* it is sent/received. (Which itself is not instantaneous, but that's a different barrel of monkeys not relevant here.)

**Lots of things can cause handshake_failure** and the *best* way to fix this is to find out specifically what the server doesn't like, usually from its logs.

But if you can't or won't do that, you have to guess. **One plausible guess is** that you (more exactly, JSSE in your JVM on behalf of your application code) is **not sending [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)**. The log from your j11+TLSv1.2 case should have had `Unable to indicate server name` and `Ignore, context unavailable extension: server_name` a few lines *before* the part you posted. Nowadays with the increasingly common use of virtual hosts and especially cloud and/or shared hosting and third-party CDNs, many servers require SNI, and will reject connections without it. You don't show enough of the j8 log to determine if it *does* send SNI, although I'm not aware of any cases where j8 does and j11 doesn't.  (There were bugs in j7 and IIRC some updates of j8 which did *not* send SNI in some cases, particularly when using Apache httpclient as you are doing via okta, but I'm pretty sure those were all fixed by 8u202.)

Comment: Appreciate the response Dave and all others as well. I did use the :trustmanager option and see that he certs are being loaded in jdk11 and the truststore mentioned. Thanks for clarifying. I am trying to find what the server doent like but the logs arent taking me anywhere. Adding more info and I believe the server name(SNI) is being provided. Please let me know if there is further logging that can be enabled.

Comment: The log you had in v4, though you've now deleted it, showed ClientHello WITHOUT server_name; what makes you think it is being sent? On all versions of j11 I have the ClientHello contains extensions pskKEmodes=45 and key_share=51 ONLY for requests offering 1.3, not for requests using 1.2 only; if you look a few lines earlier is there supported_versions=43 and what does it contain? Also NO version of Java I have logs in that format, with `Type:` and `Length:` on separate lines.

Comment: Dave, Ive added the error log again. The property host name is being called in client hello so I assumed that was what you mentioned. And the the earlier logs are from wireshark output not java logs. Extension: supported_versions (len=9)
                Type: supported_versions (43)
                Length: 9
                Supported Versions length: 8
                Supported Version: TLS 1.3 (0x0304)
                Supported Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
                Supported Version: TLS 1.1 (0x0302)
                Supported Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)

Comment: Oops! I misread v4, server_name WAS there, and now is again (as you say). Okay, the problem isn't missing SNI, and I assume your xxxx is redaction and the actual value is correct, so it's not wrong SNI. However, your log shows you ARE sending an up-to-1.3 request, not an only-1.2 request; the server _might_ dislike that, even though 1.3 was designed and tested (over years!) to work with 1.2 implementations. Exactly how are you trying to do only-1.2?

Comment: Thanks Dave for all the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Well the culprit was bluecoat. It was updated to a newer version which had a proxy bug and blocking SSL. Once SSL intercepts were disabled on bluecoat this started working.